# Bitwise operation using slick

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

How can I perform the following using slick:

```
select * from users where location = 3 and (permissions & 4 = 4);
```

Is this possible or do I have to use raw sql for this?

Answer (score 0):

If your database support SQL operators for it you can define Slick operators for it as described here: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/userdefined.html

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get bitwise operators to work by following the pattern for numeric operators

in .../util/slick/BitwiseExtension.scala

```
package ...util.slick

import slick.ast.Library.SqlOperator
import slick.lifted.{BaseExtensionMethods, ExtensionMethods, Rep}

object Library {
  val & = new SqlOperator("&")
}

trait BitwiseColumnExtensionMethods[B1, P1] extends Any with ExtensionMethods[B1, P1] {
  def & [P2, R](e: Rep[P2])(implicit om: o#arg[B1, P2]#to[B1, R]) =
    om.column(Library.&, n, e.toNode)
}

final class BaseBitwiseColumnExtensionMethods[P1](val c: Rep[P1]) extends AnyVal
  with BitwiseColumnExtensionMethods[P1, P1]
  with BaseExtensionMethods[P1]
```

in .../util/slick/package.scala

```
package ...util

import slick.ast.{ BaseTypedType, NumericTypedType }
import slick.lifted.Rep

package object slick {
  implicit def bitwiseColumnExtensionMethods[B1](c: Rep[B1])(implicit tm: BaseTypedType[B1] with NumericTypedType) = new BaseBitwiseColumnExtensionMethods[B1](c)
}
```

and then using it in a query:

```
import ...util._

Tables.users.filter({ r =>
    (r.permissions & mask) === mask
})
```

You can see how Slick will produce a query by looking at `JdbcStatementBuilderComponent` (https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/6c638ea0688345044e3d3a362fab92c76db9a85b/slick/src/main/scala/slick/jdbc/JdbcStatementBuilderComponent.scala#L378)

```
case Apply(sym: Library.SqlOperator, ch) =>
  b"\("
  if(ch.length == 1) {
    b"${sym.name} ${ch.head}"
  } else b.sep(ch, " " + sym.name + " ")(expr(_))
  b"\)"
```